# Does VS2012 still contains win32 parts? or is it only WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, com, visual-studio-2012, win32com

If it does still contains Win32 parts - which are the main ones?

Comment: As far as i know its WPF but some non-WPF components are still hosted in it, though i have no source for that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are still some non-WPF UI elements in VS 2012 -

For example, the Find and Replace *dialog* (`Edit->Find and Replace->Find in Files`) is basically unchanged for many releases of VS, and not WPF based.

You can verify this, btw, by using Spy++ - for example, the buttons in that window all have their own HWND, and using one HWND per element.

Comment: in the main shell - is there anything that's win32? or is it only window dialogs that are? (i already noticed that Open File Dialog is win32)

Comment: also, as far as i can tell - VS2012 has far LESS win32 parts than VS2010, right?

Comment: @EladKatz Yes, I believe so - a lot of older UIs were replaced, but there are still some noticable Win32 UI elements.